# Flutter showing 'No Devices' even the devices are started

Tags: flutter, development-environment

Flutter run is not working when I started the emulator and the emulator seems to work fine. Where's the problem currently running in UBUNTU

Comment: Enable `USB debugging` in your emulator and change the USB type to `File Transfer`

Comment: I tried but doesn't seems to work

Comment: Run flutter doctor on the terminal and see what is the output you are getting

Comment: First try to get you device local IP address and run these commands `adb disconnect` `adb tcpip 5555` `adb connect <DeviceIPAddress>`

Comment: The output is all tick and fine

Comment: <DeviceIPAddress> not helpful

Comment: Try to replace the <DeviceIpAddress> by your emulator local IP Address

Comment: What is the OS version in your emulator and what is your project supported version?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED ! I just cold boot my device now it works fine.